# Easiest way to interpret strings of: numbers, ',' and '-'?

Tags: string, list, python-3.x

That's a bit of a vague title but I'm writing a function that does the following:

```
'1,2,3,4' -> [1,2,3,4]  
'1,2-4'   -> [1,2,3,4]  
'1-3,4'   -> [1,2,3,4]  
'1,1,1'   -> [1]  
'3-9, 1'  -> [1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]  
'4-1,6'   -> [1,2,3,4,6]
```

',' indicates that the previous number is complete and to add it in order to the list.
'-' indicates to add all numbers inclusively between the two numbers on either side.
spaces should be avoided and duplicates should be ignored

I have some janky python code for you to get an idea of what I was going for:

```
def seasons_dict(seasons):

    season_dict = {}

    current = ''
    a = ''
    b = ''
    for i in range(len(seasons)):
        if seasons[i].isdigit():
            current = current + seasons[i]
            if (len(seasons) == (i + 1)) and (current not in season_dict):
                if a == '':
                    season_dict[current] = {}
                    current = ''
                else: 
                    b = current
                    if a == b:
                        season_dict[a] = {}
                        current = ''
                    elif b > a:
                        for s in range(int(a), int(b) + 1):
                            season_dict[str(s)] = {}
                        current = ''
                    elif a > b:
                        for s in range(int(b), int(a) + 1):
                            season_dict[str(s)] = {}
                        current = ''
        elif (seasons[i] == ','):
            if (a == '') and (current not in season_dict):
                season_dict[current] = {}
                current = ''
            elif (a != '') and (current not in season_dict):
                b = current
                if a == b:
                    season_dict[a] = {}
                    current = ''
                elif b > a:
                    for s in range(int(a), int(b) + 1):
                        season_dict[str(s)] = {}
                    current = ''
                elif a > b:
                    for s in range(int(b), int(a) + 1):
                        season_dict[str(s)] = {}
                    current = ''
                a = ''
            else:
                current = ''
        elif seasons[i] == '-':
            a = current
            current = ''

    return season_dict
```

Yes I'm aware I said list originally and now I'm dealing with a dictionary but it really doesn't make a difference. Lists are just generally easier to think about.
Thank you all in advance! Let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 0):

I think using regular expressions to parse your little mini-language would let you simplify the code a lot:

```
import re

def parse_numbers(num_str):
    results = set()
    for first, second in re.findall(r'(\d+)(?:\s*-\s*(\d+))?', num_str):
        if second:
            if int(first) > int(second):
                first, second = second, first
            results.update(range(int(first), int(second)+1))
        else:
            results.add(int(first)
    return sorted(results)
```

This might be a little more permissive than you want, since it ignores anything that's not a number or pair of numbers with a dash in between. If you give it `'1,2,foo,3-5'` it will happily parse out `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` ignoring `foo`. You could write a separate regex to validate the input if you are concerned about that. It's a bit difficult to validate and parse at the same time, so I'd do it in two separate passes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sets, sorting, parsing and range to this:

```
tests=['1,2,3,4', 
'1,2-4',   
'1-3,4' , 
'1,1,1',   
'3-9, 1',    
'4-1,6',]

for s in tests:
    uniq=set()
    for e in s.split(','):
        if '-' in e:
            t=tuple(map(int, sorted(e.split('-',1))))
            uniq |= set(range(t[0],t[1]+1)) 
        else:
            uniq.add(int(e))
    li=sorted(uniq)

    print("{:10s} -> {}".format(s, li))
```

Prints:

```
1,2,3,4    -> [1, 2, 3, 4]
1,2-4      -> [1, 2, 3, 4]
1-3,4      -> [1, 2, 3, 4]
1,1,1      -> [1]
3-9, 1     -> [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
4-1,6      -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
```